# Defender needs updated & shows me a strange message. What does this mean?

Tags: windows, windows-defender

What is the meaning of this?
[image]

I get notified that Defender needs updated & when I try to update it this pops up. OS is Windows 8.0-
Clicking help is worthless, same for searching the error number.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Did it throw that message just by pressing the update button?

Comment: Since Windows Defender is part of Windows this would be indication that Windows should either be repaired (DISM and SFC) or simply reinstalled.

Comment: Windows 8.0 has been out of support for years, replaced by 8.1, which though end of mainstream 2018 still gets security updates for another year. if you're not already on 8.1, now might be the time (or just get Win10)

Comment: "I get notified that Defender needs updated" who or what told the OP to "update" and was it from a webpage? Is this a phishing/smishing (sms) style attempt?

Comment: @Yorik - It's hidden by the error dialog.

Comment: @ramhhound it may be launching via automation etc. vbscript, sendkeys etc

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has ended support for all versions backwards from windows 8.1;
clicking  'update' any where will result in an error since Microsoft's servers are no longer reachable. . .

Comment: Windows 10 is the worst OS EVER. It never should have been released.